# How to add meta tags in header.php child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, header, meta-tags

I am trying to add meta keywords to my header for my child theme. I've copied the main header.php file over and even copied the header.php from the template parts of the theme with the meta-information but for some reason, it does not accept it.

```
<meta name="keywords" content=",  Top Dance Club,  Circuit Tribal House,  Big Room, Funky House Music,  Dance Classics,  House Music, Trash Disco, Nu Disco, Tech House, Progressive House, Electro House, Future House, Diva, Gay Anthems, Eurodance, Non-stop Dance Mix"/>
```

I know Google doesn't use these any longer but I still want them there. This should be straight forward but it's not working. I use the Customizr Pro theme and am thinking I may need to add some code to my function.php file in the child theme. The one snippet of code I found crashed my admin.

Comment: Is your child theme active? What is your folder structure to the header.php file?

Answer (score 0):

To override template parts via your child theme, you must recreate the same path structure found in the main theme in your child theme.

**Your parent theme would look something like:**

```
/wp-content/themes/themename/includes/template-parts/header.php
```

**Your child theme should then become:**

```
/wp-content/themes/themename-child/includes/template-parts/header.php
```

Comment: It does not work. I use Yoast SEO plugin, which overrides the meta-information in the header. Even if I disconnect the plugin, this solution does not work. Your answer appears to be technically correct.

Comment: Think we'd need to know more about your specific theme/child theme, in particular the template part folder structure.

Comment: The structure is different. It's wp-content/themes/customizr-pro/templates/parts/header.php but since you mentioned it - I just realized that public_html is missing from the beginning of the path. I'll go back and try it again shortly.

Comment: I give up. I disconnected Yoast SEO plugin and disabled Cloudfare. I added the correct path including public_html and it did not work. I also tried it with the header.php under the main customizr-pro path as there are two different header files in the theme. One in "parts" and the other in the main folder. Neither work. I also fixed my formatting on the meta entry and removed the comma after content =". Nothing appears to work.